# output log file from some time to some time via ssh

Tags: ssh, files, output

I have a access_log which size is neally 2GB. I want to analyze it from `2015:09:55` to `2015:09:57`, but during this period, there have more than 500 items. So I want to output and download the access_log only from `2015:09:55` to `2015:09:57` in my computer and open it in my EmEditor.

I am not good at SSH commond. I tried this not working

```
[root@server ~]# cat /var/log/httpd/access_log | (grep "2015:09:55"||grep "2015:09:56||grep "2015:09:57") > /home/usr/log_access.txt
```

Comment: What does a line of your access_log look like? Apache logs look like `[Wed Oct 11 14:32:52 2000] …` by default.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick, `66.249.67.5 - - [24/Jan/2015:09:55:56 -0500] "GET /feed/home.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 6069 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a range with regexes as delimiters with sed.

As an example, all entries, that contain anything between 2015:09:56 and 2015:09:6(something):

```
ssh host "sed -n '/2015:09:5[6-9]/,/2015:09:6/ p' /var/log/httpd/access_log"
```

to capture the output in a local file, use redirection, that is:

```
ssh host "sed -n '/2015:09:5[6-9]/,/2015:09:6/ p' /var/log/httpd/access_log" >log_snippet
```

Comment: `ssh host -p 2020 "sed -n '/2015:09:5[6-9]/,/2015:09:6/ p' /var/log/httpd/access_log"`, ssh: connect to host host port 2020: Connection refused

Comment: What is your question? You have to access the server, the way you always do. The name "host" here is just an example.

Comment: now i have seen them all print into my putty screen. how to save them into a file `/home/usr/log_access.txt`? then I will download it use filezilla. thanks.

Comment: I like it. but i have already logined into my server via SSH, can i jump to enter my SSH password again?

Comment: If you are logged in, you just need the commands:
sed -n '/2015:09:5[6-9]/,/2015:09:6/ p' /var/log/httpd/access_log >log_snippet
In this case log_snippet is on your server of course, otherwise it would be from where you logged in.

Comment: You should learn some basics of ssh and bash, if you do this or might get serious problems.